# Can "git push" hang on the same %?

Tags: git, msysgit

I am starting to use Git.  I feel it is important to point out that this was not my choice.  I have found Git to be problematic to understand but largely stable, until last month.  A week into Dec 2010 I found that I could no longer push to our "central" repository.  The process would reach 70% on writing objects and then hang.  We have no Git "experts", but I asked some of the other people that have been using it and was given a number of suggested resolutions.  Issues with Logitech webcams, attempting to do the push from Safe Mode 9 (with networking obviously), using the command line in Git bash rather than [Tortoise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN).  None worked.  What I ended up doing was uninstalling [msysgit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29#Portability) and reinstalling it.  That resolved the issue.  Or so I thought.  A couple of days ago the issue recurred.  I can no longer "push" to our repository.

I suppose I could just plan on reinstalling msysgit every month from now on, but that seems like to great a concession to me. :-)

Any idea what I can do to resolve this, or even troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the version of Git, not the OS that was the issue.  I had installed Git version 1.7.?.  The Server was running version 1.6.4.  Byt downgrading my client to 1.6.4 I have not had any issues.  Thanks for your assistence on this.  I still think I will likely go back to ClearCase until there is more support for Git within my organization.  As for adymitruk's comment "You just can't beat what Git enables you to do.", that may be true in general, but I have seen little advantage of Git over SVN for my work.  Maybe I am just not enough of a Geek.  Maybe I am just stupid as Linus say all SVN users are.

Thanks again
Pat O

Comment: Good luck, if you need help in the future, you know where to find us :)

Answer (score 1):

There may be issues with where it is hosted. I've been using git (msysgit) since 2008 and never had such an issue. I would recommend hosting the server on a linux VM though. That's made things faster and gitolite is excellent for permissions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not really an answer, but better than people who reported this on the Git mailing list got :-). I think my solution will be to go back to ClearCase, which has many issues, but works. The server is hosted at a different site. They have no Linux experience that I am aware of. So I don't think that is an alternative. Even if it were hosted here, I don't know that the head aches of making Linux work in a Windows environment would be justified.

Comment: Not many at all. Works here for us and I'm more than happy to help. Also Sitaram is always on the git channel on IRC and can help if you run into issues. Do the work now so you don't put a glass ceiling on your productivity from now on. You just can't beat what Git enables you to do.

Comment: If I were you, before you give up, hop on to the #git channel on freenode (they have a web client). Once you connect, read the prompt carefully. You must go to a page that does a captcha check before you can participate. Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is not a common problem, so I suggest you attempt a series of tests to see where the problem occurs:

- Set up a remote repository on another machine (such as your work companion's computer) and see if you can complete the transaction to that repository to see if it's a repository problem or network problem
- Try it on another network to see if there's a problem with proxy servers, NAT, etc in the way (shouldn't be an issue, but who knows what your work network is like)
- The repositories are simple directory/file structures.  Try copying the remote repository onto a flash drive, and then put it in your local machine and try to update it locally.  This eliminates the network and your update method (server, ssh, etc) from the chain of components to see if there's a problem with the repository itself (perhaps it's corrupted).

Rather than post an exhaustive list of troubleshooting possibilities which would be nearly endless, consider all the parts of the system you are interacting with and try to narrow down the problem by replacing parts of it (ie, the tool, your local repository, the remote repository, the network, etc, etc, etc)  Also, make sure you are using the tools correctly - it shouldn't take a long time to transfer a few changes.

Comment: This appears to be a reasonably common problem as I have found it documented on other forums, including having been reported on the Git forum at least twice aside from my time. In each case it was with Git hosted on a Windows machine which is not a "supported" configuration. My solution was to reinstall Git. The problem is solved for now.  BTW, copying my repository to a new client in my office did allow the push to complete from the other machine.

Comment: @Pat Well, if you are using it in an unsupported manner, then I'm not surprised you're not finding a good solution.  I would suggest going the route of a linux VM if you cannot dedicate a linux server to it.  There are also a lot of hosted solutions which would resolve your issues as you'd have dedicated support experts making sure you could use it.

Comment: Wether Git is supported on Windows or not is a point of some debate.  The majority of comments I found on the Git forum stated that it is not recommended that I one runs Git on Windows.  The Linux solution just trades one problem for another.  There is no straight forward method of integrating Linux into Windows Active/Directory.  I suppose we could use SSH keys, but then someone (probably me) would have to help everyone in this office to create an SSH Key.  This is not something I wish to do if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Just another datapoint -- this could be related to [Issue 457](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=457) on the msysgit project site.  There is a patch with a workaround (from Feb 2011), but as of today (June 13, 2011) they have not included it in a release.

Comment: Thanks for adding this here.  I had seen it and I do believe it is the issue.  Unfortunately, the patch is to turn off a fairly significant performance improvement for Windows.  The solution that we have implemented is to switch to ssh.  This is costing me a couple of hours a month ssh support time, but it cannot be helped.  I doubt the patch will ever be included in a build of Git.  The Git protocol is lower priority than ssh.  The msysgit guys are few and they are busy with other things.